# What music is sutiable for an Islamic video?

Tags: music

I do a lot of video editing, but I do not like to use music. I've been trying to find drum or duff instrumentals, but they are pretty hard to find. What do you guys recommend? (Humming?, Drums?) And would computer noises be considered instruments?

Answer (score 2):

do you need something like this :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LyDZH7xPi4k

or this :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3bWXqdISgU0

or see this channel :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d2ahNBi1p0k&list=PL_ts4LlPkQbjsmIVzvwMB78ScxVp1jEtD&index=27

or just search in youtube the term :

آهات اسلامية

Comment: Yes, but different ones preferably and one that I wouldn't be copywrited with. I guess I will have to start making my own lol

Comment: i think all those are free and open source because it's used everywhere ! :)

Comment: Thank you yeah, thats the thing its used everywhere lol. Thanks for the response though

Comment: @BkRazor welcome :)

Comment: see this also https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d2ahNBi1p0k&list=PL_ts4LlPkQbjsmIVzvwMB78ScxVp1jEtD&index=27